# Amend size of LabelField (blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry

Below class is custom label field that paints a bitmap as its background. Im overriding getprefferedwidth and getpreferredheight, will this not set the height and width of my field? Currently the width and height are not being set correctly

Thanks

```
   public class TimerLabelField extends LabelField {

        private int colour;
        private Bitmap backgroundBitmap;

    public TimerLabelField(Object text, long style, Font font, int colour,
            Bitmap backgroundBitmap) {
        super(text, style);
        this.colour = colour;
        this.backgroundBitmap = backgroundBitmap;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        if(backgroundBitmap != null){
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth(), this.backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), this.backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
        }

        graphics.setColor(this.colour);
        super.paint(graphics);

    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() 
    {
        return this.backgroundBitmap.getWidth();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() 
    {
        return this.backgroundBitmap.getHeight();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `layout(int width, int height)` as well:

```
protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    super.layout(width, height);
    setExtent(Math.min(width, this.BackgroundBitmap.getWidth()), Math.min(height, this.Backgroundbitmap.getHeight());
}
```